# How to add dev properties in quarakus app?

Tags: java, quarkus, application.properties

this is my application.properties ,which is configured to hold two db configs so we can run two separately ,one with default db ,second as test for everyday use

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle 
quarkus.datasource.username=****_res_test
quarkus.datasource.password=******************$v0yoxh
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****-nat.*****.net:3330:*****


%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=sa
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=password

%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

I have added these dependencies,one for default db as oracle second for h2

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

when I run ./mvnw quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.profile=test

I'm having the following error after trying

**Caused by: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to find a JDBC driver corresponding to the database kind 'h2' for the default datasource (available: 'oracle'). Check if it's a typo, otherwise provide a suitable JDBC driver extension, define the driver manually, or disable the JDBC datasource by adding 'quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false' to your configuration if you don't need it.**

I tried to set this "quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false" then run , but after i do so i get this time

**java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#configurationDescriptorBuilding threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Datasource must be defined for persistence unit ''.**

so after trying and trying couldn't get this running ,please help.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency> i have added this and worked,but not sure ,shouldn't ti have scope test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on this [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profiles:%7E:text=dev%20%2D%20Activated%20when%20in%20development%20mode%20(i.e.%20quarkus%3Adev)) you can see that for what you want to do you could use

```
%dev.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
%dev.quarkus.datasource.username=sa
%dev.quarkus.datasource.password=password
%dev.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

so when you run `./mvnw quarkus:dev` your application will use those setting.

The `%test` is active when running tests. (If I'm not mistaken to have this you could do ./mvnw verify etc...)

If you want to use Oracle for production, I believe you could use %prod which is "The default profile when not running in development or test mode"

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks had a problem with dependency ,added in teh comments